# Run NPM scripts synchronously

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

To start my project, I have 4 terminal commands that need executing in order, one after another and in different terminal windows:

```
npm install
gulp
php -S localhost:8001
browser-sync start --proxy "localhost:8001" --files "**/*"
```

To speed things up, I want to put theses in the `package.json` and execute them with a single command like so:

```
scripts: {
  "start": "npm install && gulp && php -S localhost:8001 && browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:8001' --files '**/*'"
}
```

But won't this run them asynchronously and in the same shell?

Comment: `&&` means that commands will be run in series, the next command is running if the previous is finished without error.

Comment: @AlexanderMac thanks for confirming. the php, gulp and browser-sync commands all continue running so need their own shell window. Is there a way to ensure that happens with the above command?

Comment: If one of the command is continue running, the next command won't be started (because the current is never finished). In this case you need to run them in own shell windows and of course they will be executed not in series.

Comment: Yeh that's the problem. I don't know how to structure the command in my `package.json` script so the commands run in their own shell windows...

Answer (score -1):

You must try [exec-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-sync) and provide the scripts command one by one.

```js
var execSync = require('exec-sync');
 
execSync('npm install');
execSync('gulp');
execSync('php -S localhost:8001');
```

Comment: But this would require the `npm install` to be run first, which is one of the scripts I'm trying to execute....